# React-native updating project gives me error : Could not find com.swmansion:react-native-reanimated:3.5.4

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I need to update an app compiled in 2019, in order to make it work on the last Android Version.

I'm on windows using npm & react-native. You can consider me a total beginner on react-native / gradle.

I updated all of the npm packages.

I updated the SDKs & gradle / gradle wrapper versions.

When i try to ./gradlew bundleRelease, i got the following error :

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:buildReleasePreBundle'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.swmansion:react-native-reanimated:3.5.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - file:/********/android/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - file:/*******/android/node_modules/react-native/android/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - file:/*********/.m2/repository/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - https://maven.google.com/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
       - file:/********/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/swmansion/react-native-reanimated/3.5.4/react-native-reanimated-3.5.4.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

(Of course ****** is the correct file path)

I looked up and found that i had to declare in my app/build.gradle :

```
    implementation "com.swmansion:react-native-reanimated:3.5.4"
```

So i added it, but it didn't change anything.

Here is my android/build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 28
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
//        agp_version = '7.2.0'
        agp_version = '8.1.1'
        androidxAppcompatVersion = "1.3.0"
        androidxAnnotationVersion = "1.3.0"
        androidxCoreVersion = "1.7.0"
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        google()
    }
}
```

Here is my app/build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")
    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]
    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []
    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdk 33
    namespace "*redacted*"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*redacted*"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 109
        versionName "1.0.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
            force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
            force 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
//            force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.72.5'
        }
//        eachDependency { details ->
//            if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' &&
//                    details.requested.name == 'hermes-android') {
//                details.useVersion '0.2.1'
//            }
//        }
    }

}



dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
//    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0' // Update to a suitable version.
//    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0' // Update to a suitable version.
//    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0' // Update to a suitable version.
//    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '3.0.9'
    implementation project(':react-native-blob-util')
    implementation project(':react-native-location')
    implementation project(':react-native-permissions')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation "com.swmansion:react-native-reanimated:3.5.4"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:hermes-android'
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-keychain')
    implementation project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-pdf')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-ble-plx')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
//    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:1.8.0'
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppcompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:$androidxAnnotationVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$androidxCoreVersion"


    implementation project(':react-native-localization')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
//    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:+'
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Here is my gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I've been working on the update for a few weeks now, but i keep getting stuck on this error, if you could provide me some help / documentation on what to do, it would be very welcomed !